# GLKView in IB will cause crash when app is run without Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard, glkview

I have an app that displays a `ViewController` at some point, which includes a `GLKView`. All defined within a storyboard.
It works just fine, that is, unless you run the app from the phone itself, not launched from within Xcode. Upon presentation of the `ViewController` and therefore the `GLKView`, the app instantly crashes.

It doesn't matter if the `Installed` checkbox is ticked or unticked for the `GLKView`. Only when I delete it from the storyboard altogether, it won't crash.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the crash log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why these things happen but I would consider them a bug. A similar situation happens when adding a `WKWebView` directly from storyboard. For both the solution is pretty simple: All you need to do is import the module for it. So in your case in your view controller add:

```
import GLKit
```

It seems otherwise the framework is not loaded or something.

With ObjectiveC the problem seems to go a level deeper. It seems that the module must manually be imported. Go to your project settings. Select your target. Select "General". Scroll down to bottom and find "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Below it find a "+" button and search for "GLKit.framework" and add it. This should fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: The `ViewController` already had `GLKit` imported.

`#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>`

Comment: @Eric My apologies, I have missed the Objective-C flag. Please see my edit. I added a solution for ObjectiveC as well.

Comment: I just solved it myself too, turns out the Console from macOS works quite well to log errors, and the error pointed out GLKView was unknown, so importing the framework makes sense.

Comment: Any chance you know why 1) You wouldn't need to import the framework in a Swift project and 2) the app would run in Xcode even without the framework imported?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Eric I don't know but if I had to guess: 1) Swift has different system of implicitly importing frameworks (On older system this didn't exist anyway. You had to always manually add them) which seems to scan the imports from your source files. 2) When attached to debugger a lot of magic happens. Most likely a huge amount of frameworks are preloaded for you in that case. Still I agree this looks very strange.